# Python Won't Download URL-Based zip File

Tags: python, download, python-requests

So I have a URL being generated from Houzz that, if I put that url into a browser, downloads the ZIP just fine.

I'm trying to download that zip with a few types of options and what I'm getting is that the files get made with 0 data in them. Just an empty file

```
finalurl = 'https://theurltomyzip/thefile.zip'
import requests
import urllib
import urllib2
file_name = 'C:\\Users\\inventoryuser\\Downloads\\test.zip'
file_name2 = 'C:\\Users\\inventoryuser\\Downloads\\test2.zip'
file_name3 = 'C:\\Users\\inventoryuser\\Downloads\\test3.zip'

print "downloading with urllib"
urllib.urlretrieve(finalurl, file_name)

print "downloading with urllib2"
f = urllib2.urlopen(finalurl)
data = f.read()
with open(file_name2, "wb") as code:
    code.write(data)

print "downloading with requests"
r = requests.get(finalurl)
with open(file_name3, "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

This results, as stated, with 3 completely blank "zip" files.

Note: If you put the string value for 'finalurl' into a browser, it immediately downloads the zip file. (I've also tried, in another iteration and without success, "allow_redirects = True")

Comment: Is `finalurl` the real url, or is it a redirect?  Browsers will automatically follow redirects, but your code examples won't.

Comment: some pages uses `JavaScript` to redirect or to generate data but `requests`/`urllib` can't run `JavaScript`. You may need `Selenium` to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`.

Comment: some pages have more restricted system and if you don't have correct headers or cookies then it will not send data. You would have to use `DevTool` in Chrome/Firefox to analyze all data send from browser when it downloads file.

Comment: Damnit. @furas I was trying to do this as an alternate way around using Selenium bindings (which I have setup); because that seems to be also stopping me at the download. I figured it must be some sort of botmanager.

Comment: if you want to use `reuqests` then you should first turn off JavaScript in web browser and then test url in web browser. If it can't works without JavaScript then maybe browser will saw some useful information. If it saws nothing then you would have to run browser with JavaScript and see in DevTools (tab "network") if JavaScript uses other url to get zip file and then you may use this url in your code. Maybe you will even find this url somewhere in HTML - maybe in JavaScript in HTML.

Comment: to get better help you should add real url in question so we could see this page. Every page may need different method to resolve problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://theurltomyzip/thefile.zip'

remote = urllib.request.urlopen(url)  # read remote file
data = remote.read()  # read from remote file
remote.close()  # close urllib request
local = open('download.zip', 'wb')  # write binary to local file
local.write(data)
local.close()  # close file
```

Note: I've test it with ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/data/structures/all/pdb/pdb106d.ent.gz

I think your code is fine, maybe there is an issue with the url.